# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: due_date (code 1):

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using eclipse to do an android development. In my app, i will have a query to get the assignment which is stored in the database. I want it to be ordered by the due date but I encountered this problem when I tried to run my app on the emulator and the emulator shows an error like this:

"Unfortunately, Assignment Manager #2 has stopped."

P/s: I already created that "due_date" column but it seems the database does not create that column in my database.

logcat:

```
05-01 05:54:54.783: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 48K, 5% free 2947K/3076K,   paused 35ms, total 37ms
05-01 05:54:54.783: I/dalvikvm-heap(2152): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.557MB for 635812-byte allocation
05-01 05:54:54.823: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 3566K/3700K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
05-01 05:54:54.963: E/SQLiteLog(2152): (1) no such column: due_date
05-01 05:54:54.973: D/AndroidRuntime(2152): Shutting down VM
05-01 05:54:54.973: W/dalvikvm(2152): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3b0cba8)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152): Process: com.mada.assignmentmanager, PID: 2152
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.mada.assignmentmanager/com.mada.assignmentmanager.AssignmentMainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: due_date (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, due_date FROM AssignmentTable ORDER BY due_date
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2788)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: due_date (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, due_date FROM AssignmentTable ORDER BY due_date
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at com.mada.assignmentmanager.AssignmentManagerDatabase.getAllAssignments(AssignmentManagerDatabase.java:88)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at com.mada.assignmentmanager.AssignmentMainActivity.onResume(AssignmentMainActivity.java:42)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5310)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
05-01 05:54:54.983: E/AndroidRuntime(2152):     ... 12 more
05-01 05:54:57.163: I/Process(2152): Sending signal. PID: 2152 SIG: 9
```

Database code:

```
package com.mada.assignmentmanager;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class AssignmentManagerDatabase {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_MODULECODE = "module_code";
public static final String KEY_ASSIGNMENTNAME = "assignment_name";
public static final String KEY_MARKSPROPORTION = "marks_proportion";
public static final String KEY_DUEDATE = "due_date";
public static final String KEY_PROGRESS = "_progress";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Assignmentdb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "AssignmentTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;
String cmd;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    private static final String CREATE_NEW_DATABASE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_MODULECODE
            + " TEXT  NOT NULL, " + KEY_ASSIGNMENTNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + KEY_MARKSPROPORTION + " INTEGER, " + KEY_DUEDATE
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_PROGRESS + " INTERGER);";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_NEW_DATABASE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w("AssignmentDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version" + oldVersion
                + " to " + newVersion
                + ", which will destroy all the old data.");
        // Drop the old table.
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE);
        // Create a new one.
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public AssignmentManagerDatabase(Context c) {
    ourContext = c;
}

public AssignmentManagerDatabase open() {
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    ourHelper.close();
}

public void createEntry(String moduleCode, String assignmentName,
        String marksProportion, String dueDate, String assignmentProgress) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_MODULECODE, moduleCode);
    cv.put(KEY_ASSIGNMENTNAME, assignmentName);
    cv.put(KEY_MARKSPROPORTION, marksProportion);
    cv.put(KEY_DUEDATE, dueDate);
    cv.put(KEY_PROGRESS, assignmentProgress);
    ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}

public Cursor getAllAssignments() {
    // String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_MODULECODE,
    // KEY_ASSIGNMENTNAME, KEY_MARKSPROPORTION, KEY_DUEDATE, KEY_PROGRESS};
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_DUEDATE };
    return ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
            null, KEY_DUEDATE);
}

public void deleteAssignment(long id) {
    ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null);
}

public Cursor getOneAssignment(long assignID) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, KEY_ROWID + "="
            + assignID, null, null, null, null);
}

}
```

Is it because I did something wrong in the onUpgrade() part?

Comment: The typo BobMalooga discovered doesn't really matter. The datatype can be anything, really, and if there's a syntax problem you'd get an exception. The reason was that you had an older version of the database around. For reference, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run

Answer (score 5):

The table isn't created due to this error:

```
KEY_PROGRESS + " INTERGER);";
```

Remove the first 'R'. It should be:

```
KEY_PROGRESS + " INTEGER);";
```

Comment: What a catch! bob + 1

Comment: ;) Did you see the movie?

Comment: Thanks @BobMalooga , I just make an correction on that but I still get same error

Comment: @Kween delete the application and run a fresh app. If still it has problem then upload new error logs.

Comment: Also try to comment out the onUpgrade method, which actually doesn't seem to be  useful, since you don't manage the database version.